# Archivos planos

Tags: php, array, bucles, explode

Consulta: Tengo un trabajo y quiero guardarme en una variable todo lo que esta entre comillas dobles

Ahi pongo toda la linea de como es

> 10758473BAEcobici,591,2021-04-10 20:38:24 UTC,2BAEcobici,002 - Retiro
> I,"Ramos Mejia, Jose Maria, Dr. Av. & Del Libertador
> Av.",-58.3747151,-34.5924233,2021-04-10 20:48:15 UTC,95BAEcobici,095 -
> ESMERALDA,ESMERALDA 516,-58.3781678,-34.6021121,86840BAEcobici,ICONIC

Bueno es esa la linea , yo quiero agarrar lo que esta entre comillas dobles , o sea todo lo que aparece ahí. De acuerdo a lo dicho quise hacerlo con un **explode** pero no se que ponerle que me lo separe por comillas dobles pero no sale! Esto es en lenguaje php

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Debes incluir lo que has intentado, mediante un [mcve]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Usar [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) y [`strrpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php) podría ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Si sabes lo que quieres recoger puedes usar [str_getcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-getcsv.php)